# SQL Server 2016 - SSMS Display only DB's granted to user

Tags: sql-server-2016

I've been searching around the webs on how to be able to display **ONLY** the databases that have been assigned to a user.

### Case Scenario:

*User1* & *User2* should have access to databases *One*, *Two* & *Three*.

If *User1* & *User2* are added as db_owners of databases *One*, *Two* & *Three* they still see **all databases** within the server on SSMS.

Granted they don't have access to modify databases four, five etc.. but they can still see them in SSMS.

I want them **ONLY** to be able to see databases they have direct control over.

I can revoke the view_databases permissions from *User1* & *User2*, but then they don't see *One*, *Two* & *Three* even if they've were added to them; they do not display in SSMS.

Only if I change the owner of one to User1 will User1 see it in SSMS.

My problem is that I need to segment which users see which DB and only those DB's and nothing else and I can't assign the owner to more than 1 user.

I've seen this has been an issue for a while.  Is it fixed in SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you now could do it via roles.  This was previously not possible, but should be possible now on SQL 2017 (unfortunately, I could not test it myself as I don't have Ms SQL 2017 yet).

From realease notes:

> DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL is a new class of securable, supporting
>   CONTROL, ALTER, REFERENCES, TAKE OWNERSHIP, and VIEW DEFINITION
>   permissions. ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS is now visible in
>   sys.fn_builtin_permissions. (CTP 1.0)

First you would need to deny all view to public to all databases you want to structure your view right:
`DENY VIEW any DATABASE to public`

The whole example for *DB1*:

```
USE DB1;
GO
DENY VIEW any DATABASE to public;
GO
-- DB role workers owned by db_owner
CREATE ROLE workers AUTHORIZATION db_owner;
GO
-- add users to the roles
ALTER ROLE workers ADD User1;
ALTER ROLE workers ADD User2;

-- granting control of the database
GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::<datbase_name> To workers;
```

**Edit**

**Note (from MSDN):**
If you grant `CREATE DATABASE` and `ALTER ANY DATABASE` permissions to a login and do not deny `VIEW ANY DATABASE` to the login, the login can see all rows in sys.databases.

**Permission poster:**

The CONTROL SERVER permission has all permissions on the instance of SQL Server or SQL Database.

• The CONTROL DATABASE permission has all permissions on the database.

• Permissions do not imply role memberships and role memberships do not grant 
permissions. (E.g. CONTROL SERVER does not imply membership in the sysadmin fixed server role. Membership in the db_owner role does not grant the CONTROL DATABASE permission.)  However, it is sometimes possible to impersonate between roles and equivalent permissions.

• Granting any permission on a securable allows VIEW DEFINITION on that securable. It is an implied permissions and it cannot be revoked,
but it can be explicitly denied by using the DENY VIEW DEFINITION statement.

• SQL Database permissions refer to version 12.

• Object owners can delete them but they do not have full permissions on them.

• A DENY on a table is overridden by a GRANT on a column. However, a subsequent DENY on the table will remove the column GRANT.